# spark-cassandra-connector configuration: concurrent.reads vs input.reads_per_sec

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

feeling confused when reading https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#read-tuning-parameters

**concurrent.reads**: Sets read parallelism for joinWithCassandra tables.

**input.reads_per_sec**: Sets max requests per core per second for joinWithCassandraTable

decription for concurrent.reads from a SDE in Datastax: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/spark-connector-user/PaQm1LT7Qlk/h41WLnHfBAAJ

```
Concurrent reads set to 4 means in a 4 core spark executor means, 16 requests will run MAX at the same time.
```

looks like **concurrent.reads** does the same thing as **input.reads_per_sec**.

what is the true difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same, but could be treated as related...

- `concurrent.reads` defines how many simultaneous requests per core could be sent simultaneously (so-called [in-flight requests](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/pooling/)).  In some cases you can lower it from default to avoid overload of Cassandra nodes from handling too many requests in parallel;
- `input.reads_per_sec` defines how many requests per core per second could be executed.

Comment: from your description, the difference between first and second is that "could be sent" and "could be executed". 
1. Can you provide more detail about this? 
2. can i lower "input.reads_per_sec" to avoid the cluster overload? 
3. if question 2 is yes, then should the value be the same as "concurrent.reads"? do they take the same effect ?
thanks

Comment: 1st option (concurrent reads) is how many queries are executed in parallel by one core - if Cassandra is able to answer quickly, you can get more requests per second. 2nd option is controlling how many requests per second will be executed... You need to tune one of them - I suggest to start with 1st option

Comment: can you also tell the difference between input.reads_per_sec and input.fetch.size_in_rows ?

Comment: `fetch.size_in_rows` defines the size of the page: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/paging/